# Can't power off ubuntu in dual mode

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I know my questions have a lot of similar ones but I couldn't find any that properly describe my problem.

I have a Dual boot with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04. I made it without any specific maneuver, just installed Ubuntu in top of Windows. I deactivate all fast boot at the time.

I switched to the proprietary drivers for Ubuntu (Nvidia 515). I say it because I know it can have some impact. Everything was working fine for some months.

I updated Ubuntu with the update manager recently. I got some message about UEFI and got some blue screen with some choices to do. I just hit continue, never saw it again.

But now I have a problem. Every time I power off Ubuntu:

The Pc seems to power off normally, black screen, keyboard light and all leds stopping.
When I start with the power button it starts the classic led sequences but stay stuck on a black screen.
The only way to get back to the Grub menu is to hit the physical power off button for a solid 10 sec (even staying after led and keybord shut off) and then restarting it.

My feeling is that the ubuntu update reactivated some secure boot or fast boot and now when I power off Ubuntu I am stuck in a in between mode after grub and before Ubuntu that doesnt work.

Anybody know how to debug that and deactivate it? What I want is that:

Powering off Ubuntu get me back to GRUB menu on next restart

Thanks in advance,

Luc

Comment: Update UEFI before anything else. Then, with the current or the upgrade version you may want to assure Fast Boot is actually disabled. Ubuntu updates don't change those UEFI settings but now alongside OS updates sometimes firmware (UEFI and others) updates are installed in some select models and one of those may have reset the settings to the default values.

Comment: As I said I found a lot of topic talking about this issues and especially fast boot but couldn't find one matching my case and explaining how to check if fast boot is on and how to deactivate it for my Ubuntu 22.04 under my dual boot

Comment: Fast Boot is a UEFI setting. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu, Windows or dual-booting.

Comment: Hooo, that's the part I didn't get. I thought it was linked to the OS. I choosed the last option from dual boot allowing me to go into the bios settings and deactivated fastboot

Comment: It's often confused with Fast Startup, a Windows feature. Neither is related to what you report. The problem is likely the blue screen you ignored because 1. if you're dual-booting with Windows 11 you can't disable Secure Boot, the easy and dirty solution used up until now to allow unsigned drivers; 2. Because of the previous point we must now manually sign the Nvidia drivers and that "blue screen" was probably the mokutil asking for that. What happened next? Nvidia drivers are prevented from loading resulting in a black screen.

Comment: Ok, really good explanation of the problem ^^. I guess I'm down to force shutdown my computer quite often then :/.